# Program giving inaccurate value

Tags: dart, floating-accuracy

The below program calculates 2<sup>62</sup> + 2<sup>61</sup> + 2<sup>60</sup> + ... + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>.

Using `double` type to store `sum`:

```
double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
    sum += pow(2.0, i);
    // print("i : $i sum : $sum");
  }
  print(sum);
```

### OUTPUT:

```
9223372036854776000.0
```

It is clear that answer should be an `odd` number but the `sum` is : `9223372036854776000.0` which is an `even` number.

When I change the sum to int data type it's giving the accurate result:

Using `int` type to store `sum`:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
  sum += pow(2.0, i).toInt();
  //print("i : $i sum : $sum");
}
print(sum);
```

### OUTPUT:

```
9223372036854775807
```

When the datatype is double why the summation is generating wrong result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `double` only has 53 significant bits in its significand, whereas your number has 63.

52 are stored in the primary significand field, with the leading `1` bit of the 53-bit binary fraction as implicit.

[image: 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 52 significand bits]

Comment: It must be `53` significant bits https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int-class.html isn't it?

Comment: It must be `53` significant bits because both the expressions are generating same result `print(1 << 53);`  & `print(pow(2.0, 53));`

Comment: There are 52 bits of storage for the mantissa, with an implied leading `1` bit. So if you count the implied bit, then you can consider it to be 53.

Comment: The term used by the IEEE 754 standard is “significand” rather than “mantissa.” The fraction portion of a floating-point representation is a significand. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Significands are linear; adding to a significand adds to the number represented. Mantissas are logarithmic; adding to a mantissa multiplies the number represented.

Comment: @Udesh Note that printing `1 << 53` and `pow(2.0, 53)` doesn't necessarily tell you anything about the number of significant bits.  Bits in the significand control *precision*, not magnitude.  Both expressions require only one significant bit.  Depending on the algorithm used to convert binary floating-point numbers to decimal strings, both expressions could end up printing the same thing¹.  A better test is checking `var x = (1 << 53).toDouble(); print(x == x + 1);`.

Comment: ¹ For example, using the standard C library implementation on my system, `int64_t x = 1; x <<= 62; printf("%"PRId64"\n", x); printf("%f\n", (double) x);` prints the same value (excluding trailing fractional zeroes).  Dart happens to print different values because it converts `double` to `String` differently.

Comment: How is the leading 1 bit implicit when the significand does not have a leading 1 bit, as for subnormal operands?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is a matter of taste as to whether to call the significand 52 bits or 53 bits. I tend to prefer a measure of the information content, which is 52 bits. But I'm fine either way. From Wikipedia: "The significand is characterized by its width in (binary) digits, and depending on the context, the hidden bit may or may not be counted towards the width of the significand. For example, the same IEEE 754 double-precision format is commonly described as having either a 53-bit significand, including the hidden bit, or a 52-bit significand, excluding the hidden bit."

Comment: There is an implicit leading `1` in all cases except for the exponent equal to zero.

Comment: @MarkAdler: The IEEE 754 standard describes the significand throughout in terms of the number of digits in it mathematically. The “significand” is always the significand of the floating-point representation. This correctly describes its mathematical properties; all arithmetic and other floating-point operations behave as if the significand has 53 bits, because it does. The field used to represent its trailing bits is the “trailing significand field,” because it is the trailing bits, not all the bits.

Comment: @MarkAdler: So you know the leading bit from the exponent field. It is in fact explicitly encoded via the exponent field: The leading bit is the value of the function “If the exponent field is non-zero (and not all ones), 1, otherwise, 0.”

Comment: @jamesdlin `var x = (1 << 53).toDouble(); print(x == x + 1);` this is a very good example but `print(pow(2.0, 53));` will give the `9007199254741092.0` and `print(((1 << 53) + 1).toDouble());` will also give the same result because `pow` method returns `double` and **2^53** is the max value that could be stored by significand bits.

Comment: @Udesh No, 2^53 would require using at most one bit from the significand.  It tells you nothing about the number of bits used by the significand.  2^53 - 1, on the other hand, would use all of the significand bits.